# Facing Error : -101 THE STATEMENT IS TOO LONG OR TOO COMPLEX in IBM DB2 SQL Run

Tags: sql, db2, heap-memory, monitoring, query-engine

**Introduction:**
I work on DB2 databases in one of my projects. In one of the databases, a job that executes an SQL is running.

**Problem:**
For the past few days, this job has been failing with the below error code.

> -101 THE STATEMENT IS TOO LONG OR TOO COMPLEX

**Description:**

1. Query is optimized to class 7.
2. Query consists of a select statement with complex and multiple joins. This select statement is used to insert data into a table.
   ex:

> INSERT INTO table_name (column_name_1, column_name_2, ....)
>
> SELECT * from table_name_1 t1 join table_name_2 t2 on
> t1.col_1=t2.col_2;

However, the joins are much more lengthy and complex. Plus, a large number of columns are involved.

3. This query was running for a long time in the system but never failed. This query was also never changed.
4. The number of record counts in the source tables is also reducing with each passing day because the application is about to get decommissioned.

**Solution Attempts:**

1. I tried to look for this error on the Internet and got this [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=codes-101).

Based on this I doubled the STMTHEAP value and the query ran but it failed again the next day. I further doubled the STMTHEAP value and then it ran but it failed again the next day. This is going on till date.

2. I also tried to set the STMTHEAP value to Automatic but the result was the same as above.

**Other resources that I used:**

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=parameters-stmtheap-statement-heap-size

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ias?topic=parameters-sortheap-sort-heap-size

**Ask:** Can any of you help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Please share the OS - the one link points to Db2 for z/OS and the other one is Db2 LUW...

Comment: If the query previously ran successfully, but has not changed, then it is your job to discover what __did__ change (and then consider backing out that change). For example, something about the Db2-server environment changed, versions, fixpacks, patches, configuration, operating environment, other programs or components changed that are sharing the same RAM as the db2-server, or the schema changed (views/indexes/triggers/constraints).

Comment: anything in the diagnostic logs?